# Auto deploy git pull if master branch is updated

Tags: git, deployment, auto

I have 4 different sites on Linux server, and a repo on bitbucket. 
How can I update (overwrite) folders and files which are host on same server and different domain name, **after repo (master branch) is updated?**

Answer (score 0):

I use,
**git ftp init** and **git ftp push** using bitbucket pipeline page.

```
..
apt-get -qq install git-ftp
git ftp init --user FTPuser --passwd FTPpass ftp://mydomain/serverIPaddress;
..
```